# Why standard paper size are missing in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am wondering why by default the standards A0, A1, A2 are missing on Illustrator.

Is there any rationale behind this?

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is answerable without mere speculation, to be honest. Why Adobe does/doesn't do stuff is something you'd need to ask them.

Comment: Although it does not look like this today its because they have tried to minimize the size of the list. Its only later that they have included a gazillion presets for phones and devices that this becomes a wierd issue. Realistically once you strart including screen presets you should stop using a dropdown and use something more searchable and then you would include these. But note its not just iso sized paper that gets the shaft  also the more poster sized US papers are limitted in size. Then you should also iclude papers with crop allowance etc.

Comment: Frankly I think the list is a bit silly. I mean why not postcard sizes? Poster sizes?Banner sizes? Billboard sizes? Business card sizes? After all, they now include a ton of screen sizes. The defaults are meant as a "shortcut" not a catch all. That's why there's a with and height field in the new document window.

Answer (score 2):

By default adobe tries to give you only the most common page sizes.
But you can add new ones by opening one of the preets and saving a new file.

They are located somewhere like this:

(path will be be different on windows or if app version is not the same)

```
~/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe Illustrator 25/en/New Document Profiles/
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is because many of the standards, although they are standards, they are not standard.

Do you know there is a C series? and Din? and the Swedish have a D, E, F, and G? There are a ton of sizes and variants: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size

Imagine scrolling through dozens and dozens of file sizes to find the one you needed. They are standards... but not where you live or for what you use them.

---

I assume that the rationale for those Ax examples you mention is that if a user knows what he needs, he can explore and add the paper size he needs. If a user does not know, he could be working on the wrong paper size, for example, for times as big, and starting having performance issues when he rasterizes elements on the artboard.